# different line in ngFor with different component input

Tags: angular

I created a component named `progress-bar` which defines an input `progress`.
Then I use it in a `ngFor` loop in the view as below.

in the view, all progress bars are visible with 0% progress by default (`loadProgress = 0`). I expect that when I click the button in each line, the corresponding progress bar can show the progress from 0% to 100% (`loadProgress value goes from 0 to 100 by time).

**My issue**

When I click any botton, all progress bars are moving, because they all link to the very same variable `loadProgress`. I know that the input of each should be different, but I am not sure how to construct it. Shall I change the input of the component?

**View**

```
<item *ngFor="let item of items;">
  <progress-bar [(progress)]="loadProgress"></progress-bar>
  <button (click)="progressMove()"></button>
</item>
```

**component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'progress-bar',
  templateUrl: 'progress-bar.html'
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {

  @Input('progress') progress;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: We are all these progress bars supposed to display? If you have a single loadProgress value to display, why are you creating several progress bars, and not just one?

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully more clear now

Comment: No. You haven't answered my questions. What are those progress bars supposed to display? We can't tell you how to do something if you don't say what you want to do.

Comment: I thought I answered. They are just progress bar rendered by tricks of CSS, like this pic http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/pure-css3-progress-bar.jpg . the progress is controlled by the value of `loadProgress`

Comment: **the** progress? So you have **one** progress? If so, why do you have **several** progress bars? What should **each** progress bar display? The progress of what?

Comment: @JBNizet please let him check my answer and if it's not what he wants we'll try to figure out together :)

Comment: There are multiple progresses. Each line has a `progress-bar` and a `button`. when any button is clicked,  the progress-bar of that line will move from 0% to 100%.

Comment: @XiXiao then please, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `progress` variable in each of your items.

```
<item *ngFor="let item of items;">
  <progress-bar [progress]="item.progress || 0"></progress-bar>
  <button (click)="item.progress = 100"></button>
</item>
```

Since you do not declare the progress in your item object you should be careful, hence the `|| 0`

See example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vIfVKCFXCD6xWmpm5WK?p=preview

Comment: bidirectional binding to a non-assignable expression doesn't make much sense. But the OP is also not clear on why he would have bidirectional binding.

Comment: Why would my expression be non assignable? You got me worried so I tested it: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vIfVKCFXCD6xWmpm5WK?p=preview In my case the material component is well built and the `|| 0` is not necessary, but still I recommend it to prevent null values.

Comment: I think you get my point. but the ` || 0` will throw `Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 11 in [item.p || 0=$event] `. If I remove it, the page displays well. Now it is more of a coding issue for me.

Comment: @Ploppy now you've got your answer.

Comment: I accidentally double the `=`, you can see the code in plunker  in the above comment, and it works.

Comment: @JBNizet what it the `==` typo you were talking about?

Comment: No. `[(progress)]="item.progress || 0"` is a shortcut for `[progress]="item.progress || 0" (progressChange)="item.progress || 0 = $event"`. Assigning a value to `item.progress || 0` makes no sense.

Comment: I didnt copy the `==`, in my code it is `<progress-bar [(progress)]="item.p || 0"></progress-bar>` and `<button (click)="item.p = 100"></button>`, but I see your plunker works. Give me some time to figure this out...

Comment: Well ok I forgot to remove it... Please @XiXiao don't put two way databinding on your progress property, only one way: `[progress]`. Tested on local and it worked too.

Comment: @Ploppy thank you! removing the two-way-databinding did work. I didn't know that we can, in the view, to create properties of object on the fly. Now I learned. I will also study what `two-way-binding` really means.  @JBNizet Thank you too, I should have draw a diagram in my question to clear things up.

Comment: @XiXiao You should just have answered my question: I want to display the progress **of each item**". Just answering that question would have made you realize that the progress is a property of the item, and would thus have led to the solution.